# how to make a variable change from the text "1m" into "1000000" in python

Tags: python, numbers

I have variables with values like 1.7m 1.8k and 1.2b how can I convert them to a real number value for example

```
1.7m = 1700000
1.8k = 1800
1.2b = 1200000000
```

Comment: -1: No Sample Code for stuff you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using `re`:

```
input = '17k, 14.05m, 1.235b'

multipliers = { 'k': 1e3,
                'm': 1e6,
                'b': 1e9,
              }

pattern = r'([0-9.]+)([bkm])'

for number, suffix in re.findall(pattern, input):
    number = float(number)
    print number * multipliers[suffix]
```

Comment: Or even `pattern = r'([0-9.]+)(%s)' % '|'.join(multipliers)` to avoid the minor repetition of units in there.

Comment: @Will, being that `[bkm]` will only match one character, I don't see how there could be a "minor repetition of units in there". I do like your suggestion of doing a join on multipliers, but not for the reason you stated.

Comment: He is saying you can use the already-specified dictionary keys to fill out the RE rather than retyping 'bkm'.

Comment: But i considered that less easy to understand in this simple case.  If the dict had all the SI prefixes in it or somesuch, I would definitely have done that.

Comment: Using regex here is quite unnecessary.

Comment: Mike: Please feel free to provide a simpler or more effective answer.

Comment: @Joe, Vicki Laidler's answer uses the same technique as yours except that it grabs the last character directly rather than based on matching a regular expression. I suspect most people would find that solution more readable; I know I did.

Comment: @Mike: There are more than one way to solve a problem, and I've learned that it's good to adopt the unix philosophy of being forgiving in your input and precise in output.... This example shows that the regex can pull out the formatted numbers even with noise characters such as ' ' and ',', and even extracts many such numbers from the input with very little additional work.  The other solution solves the problem but is more "brittle".

Answer (score 11):

I would define a dictionary:

```
tens = dict(k=10e3, m=10e6, b=10e9)
```

then

```
x='1.7m'
factor, exp = x[0:-1], x[-1].lower()
ans = int(float(factor) * tens[exp])
```

Comment: +1: Allows someone to split the hair of `m` meaning 1e6 or 1024*1024.

Comment: The dictionary approach is problematic due to where I intend to implement this. but thanks. I'll update what I went with in a little bit

Comment: "problematic"?  That's meaningless.  Could you explain why a simple solution won't work?

Comment: @Pevo, The usage of a dictionary here is exactly the same as the usage in the accepted answer.

Comment: Dude isn't the python 10e3 == 10000?? Shouldn't it be 1e3, 1e6 .. ??

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in a units library like `quantities` or `unum`.

Answer (score 1):

Using lambda:

```
>>> tens = {'k': 10e3, 'm': 10e6, 'b': 10e9}
>>> f = lambda x: int(float(x[:-1])*tens[x[-1]])
>>> f('1.7m')
17000000
>>> f('1.8k')
18000
>>> f('1.2b')
12000000000
```