# Numeric value as a string and convert to actual numeric

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-re

I found this thread  [how to make a variable change from the text "1m" into "1000000" in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449848/how-to-make-a-variable-change-from-the-text-1m-into-1000000-in-python)

My string values are in a column within a pandas dataframe. The string/0bkects values are like 18M, 345K, 12.9K, 0, etc.

```
values = df5['Values']

multipliers = { 'k': 1e3,
                'm': 1e6,
                'b': 1e9,
              }

pattern = r'([0-9.]+)([bkm])'

for number, suffix in re.findall(pattern, values):
    number = float(number)
    print(number * multipliers[suffix])
```

Running the code gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/thebu/Documents/Python Projects/trading/screen.py", line 19, in <module>
    for number, suffix in re.findall(pattern, values):
  File "C:\Users\thebu\Anaconda3\envs\trading\lib\re.py", line 223, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `for value in values: for number, suffix in re.findall(pattern, value):
    number = float(number)
    print(number * multipliers[suffix])`

Comment: This may be more appropriate for your needs (there was one more better answer but can’t find it right now) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684548/convert-the-string-2-90k-to-2900-or-5-2m-to-5200000-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thanks to @moy for sharing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684548/convert-the-string-2-90k-to-2900-or-5-2m-to-5200000-in-pandas-dataframe the checked solution solved my issue. Did not even see this option in the search.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using regex:

```
import re
def get_word(s):
    # find word
    r = re.findall(r'[a-z]', s)
    # find numbers
    w = re.findall(r'[0-9]', s)
    if len(r) > 0 and len(w) > 0:
        r = r[0]
        v = multipliers.get(r, None)
        if v:
            w = int(''.join(w))
            w *= v
            
        return round(w)

df['col2'] = df['col'].apply(get_word)

print(df)

   col      col2
0  10k     10000
1  20m  20000000
```

**Sample Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['10k', '20m']})
```